# How can I set up a DialogBox in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I would like to have a box appear in the screen (some kind of textfield) and want to make it look like the static character is talking to the user (like the link below). The text needs to be slowly shown to the user (not all at once). I'm not sure the best way to implement this. Also, I'm not sure how to wrap the text within the box.

http://lightsendgame.com/images/screenshots/CrystalsRoom.JPG

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get a better understanding on how to make sure you get the answer you want from us

Answer (score 0):

You can create a UIView with a UILabel inside and set the alpha to 0. Whenever you want the box to appear (on button press for example) you can execute a UIAnimation block to set the alpha to 1. This will give the fade in effect you want.

Comment: I don't want all the words in the box to fade to the screen at once but each word in sequence.

Answer (score 0):

How you display the text is up to you, use the styling in xCode for this, most of us aren’t the best of designers ;)

About the text which slowly comes in to view, you can iterate through a string and keep on adding the next letting in the string to another string. After you’ve added one letter to the second string, output this second string to the user. This will go pretty quick though, if you want to slow this down you can make the thread sleep for an x amount between the iterations.

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

var text:String = “Slowly old-school displaying text is awesome!"
var scrollingText:String = “"

var label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 100))

for char in text{
    scrollingText = "\(scrollingText)\(char)"
    label.text = scrollingText
}
```

Comment: I'm using SpriteKit right now and can't add the UILabel object as a sub-child to the current scene. I can create the label with SKLabelNode but cannot get the text wrapping to work.

Comment: If you want to use a SKLabelNode, you can just replace the UILabel by an SKLabel node and in the for loop set your SKLabelNone variable’s text atribute (.text) to scrollingText

Comment: Sure, I can create a rectangle on the screen and then write text on top of it using SKLabelNode. But the text does not wrap around the rectangle as it does in the link provided by my original post. Using your scrollingTet will just have the text run off the screen.

Comment: I got the wrapping to work a third party library but I couldn't get the tread to correctly sleep between each append. Could you help with that?